# How to access the REST API provided by GIT LAB?

Tags: rest, gitlab, postman

https://api.github.com/repos/YourUsername/YourRepo/contents/file.txt

This is the endpoint of GitHub but in the GitLab API documentation, there is no endpoint mentioned. Any suggestion is highly appreciated.

Comment: Are you authenticating?

Answer (score 0):

```
GET /projects/:id/repository/files/:file_path
```

for your example curl would be

```sh
curl --header 'PRIVATE-TOKEN: <your_access_token>' 'https://gitlab.example.com/api/v4/projects/<your project id>/repository/files/file%2Etxt?ref=master'
```

More details in [docs](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/repository_files.html)